# What motivated Green to develop his theorem in order to calculate work for a non conservative vector field?

Tags: mathematicians, electricity

I am somewhat amazed at the depth of the theorem but I believe it involved his work with electricity and magnetism. Additionally I don't think he had a formal education.  I have not found much on this historical development in the context of electricity and magnetism.  Most work centers around Faraday and Maxwell's brilliant unification. Can someone shed more light on this?

Comment: Are you referring to Green's theorem?

Comment: Yes.  Green's and Stokes theorems were tailor made for the description of the fields of electricity and magnetism is what I am assuming.  They appear to be amazing leaps of progress like a bolt out of the blue but I am sure there was a lot of background work behind the scene that I am not aware of.